# Как записать разное двоичное представление в union?

Tags: массивы, память, структуры

Есть чудесная структура union в С++, все элементы которой ссылаются на одну и ту же область памяти.
Допустим элементы представлены массивами и выглядят следующим образом

```
union Dex {
    unsigned __int64 aa[2] = { '\0' };
    unsigned long int bb[4];
    unsigned short int cc[8];
};
```

Имеется какое-то огромное 22-значное число, которое я записываю в массив

```
int symbols[32];
```

Начиная со старшего байта, я хочу записать данное число в область памяти, выделенный под вышеупомянутый **юнион**.
Т.е. обращаясь к

```
cc[7]
```

я желаю узнать последнее 16-битное целочисленное от своего огромного числа.
Однако, если начинать записать с

```
 unsigned short int cc[8]
```

в `bb[3]` это будет выглядеть с точностью наоборот
Сперва выводится `cc[7]`, а далее `cc[6]`.
Как возможно разрешить эту проблему?

Comment: видимо явно писать наоборот. хотя сначала надо посмотреть на какой архитектуре выполняется приложение, на разных архитектурах используется разный порядок байт. может использовать функции на подобии htons которые правильно для данной платформы переводят порядок в "сетевой". https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: размер symbols явно больше размера Dex.